# Central Limit problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The times that patients spend in a doctor’s surgery have mean 5 minutes, and standard deviation 2 minutes. On one particular day, the doctor sees 30 patients during his surgery which starts at 4.30pm. Find an approximate probability that she finishes with her last patient before 6.50pm.

Now Letting Y = ∑30 from i=1-30
By the Central Limit Theorem Y ∼ N[150, 120] approximately. I know that im needing to find P[Y < 140] but i don't know how to find out what that value is. I'm sure im missing something blindingly obvious but i don't know how to look up that result in tables. I would really appreciate anyones help on the matter

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\Pr(Y<140) & = \Pr\left( \frac{Y-150}{\sqrt{120}} < \frac{140-150}{\sqrt{120}} \right) \\[10pt]
= {} &  \Pr\left(Z<\frac{140-150}{\sqrt{120}}\right) = \Phi\left(\frac{140-150}{\sqrt{120}}\right).
\end{align}

Comment: sorry you kind of lost me there. where did the 104 come from? and how can i look up a negative value for z in statistical tables? thanks

Comment: but even with 140 instead of 104 i still can't look up a negative value for z in tables can i?

Comment: Use symmetry of the normal distribution and look up the positive value.

Comment: so i  just always need to look up the absolute value of the sum?

Comment: If you have a table that gives you $\Phi(a)$ where $a>0$, and tells you, for example, that $\Phi(a)=0.72$, then you can conclude that $\Phi(-a)=1-0.72=0.28$. ${}\qquad{}$